# RSA implementation with PHP

Tags: php, runtime, rsa

I'm trying to program an implementation of the RSA algorithm. For that I need to compute modular exponentiations with very big numbers in PHP.
For example: c^d Mod n, where c,d,n are about 1024 bits long.
This works with bcpowmod, but the runtime is very bad. The computation of one such number needs about 2-3 secs. In Java with BigInteger and in JavaScript with an equal implementation of BigInteger the same step needs ca. 0.04 secs.
Is there another way in PHP, or how else could I do this server-side?
This is the code in PHP:

```
$c = "alongnumber";
$d = "alongnumber";
$n = "alongnumber";
$m = bcpowmod($c,$d,$n);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: just found the PHP function gmp_powm() which is MUCH faster